# Access surrounding HTML elements through JavaScript with no context

Tags: javascript, dom, element

What I want is to be able to **work on context-free HTML elements surrounding 'entry points' (like `<script>` tags or events) using JavaScript**. I have some tight restrictions on what I can do.

### Summary

1. I have multiple user-generated blocks of HTML which need to be processed on their own, as they load.
2. The content of these blocks can contain similar blocks, with similar behaviour.
3. The content will also need to be duplicated once, possibly restarting execution of the scripts mentioned in 2.
4. These blocks are generated from static templates and cannot (initially) contain unique identifying data, like IDs or random attribute values.
5. These blocks can also be generated through AJAX, which is out of my control. They will need to take care of themselves as they appear, without relying on any order of execution.

### Background

This is for a forum software, where certain BBCode tags, say `[tag]content[/tag]` are replaced with fixed HTML. I have no access to any server-side scripting, so the replacements are context-independent, i.e. always the same.
For example, `[tag]{content}[/tag]` would turn into something like:

```
<span ...>
  ...
  {content}
  ...
  <!-- script entry point -->
</span>
```

I need to do some client-side processing around the time when the data is loaded.

I cannot change the requirements of the problem. The end product is code for generating tabs, like:

```
[tabspace]
  [tab]content 1[/tab]
  [tab]
    content 2, and
    nested tabs:
    [tabspace]...[/tabspace]
  [/tab]
[/tabspace]
```

The content that is output by the script consists in the "tab buttons" themselves, which would link to their respective `content`.

### Restrictions

1. I cannot use IDs. Everything must be or start as a context-free replacement of the template.
2. `[tag]`s can be nested.
3. The script needs to duplicate some of the content, parts of which can be similar scripts and so on. This messes up scripts which are already running on the outer pairs of tags. I have a bottom-up solution to solve this, but it relies on starting scripts at any depth without worrying about similar surroundings. (another way to phrase it)
4. These tags can be loaded dynamically in any post on the page, at any time, using AJAX.
5. There can be scripts at any point in the template, to make the problem easier.

### What I tried

1. Using JS to dynamically output a `<span id='something random'></span>` as it loads, search for the given ID and use its location to find the surrounding elements. It doesn't work when I load pages dynamically and when tags are nested.
2. Give a class to the surrounding element and find the last element of its kind. This doesn't work because we may have updates in the middle of the page, after it's loaded.

### Solutions which I'd rather *avoid*

1. Using `<img src='bogus' onerror='script entry point'/>`, I can run a script and access surrounding tags using `this`. But I'd rather not use broken links and errors to solve a simple and pertinent problem.